# Gnuplot - plotting a file using another field as a label

Tags: gnuplot

(I wouldn't be suprised if this is a duplicate, I can't find the right search term to find it though)

I have a data file of the form (simplified a bit):

```
date       time       label      value
2013-03-17 10:09:28   thing 1    54
2013-03-17 10:09:32   thing 2    20
2013-03-17 10:10:02   thing 3    35
2013-03-17 10:10:03   thing 1    59
2013-03-17 10:10:21   thing 1    64
2013-03-17 10:10:37   thing 3    37
2013-03-17 10:10:37   thing 2    40
2013-03-17 10:10:42   thing 3    41
2013-03-17 10:10:44   thing 2    59
```

...and what I want to do is create a multi-line plot, each of 'thing 1', 'thing 2' and 'thing 3', and have Gnuplot automatically label them accordingly.

If I split the file into separate datasets, one for each label, then I know I can do a multi-line plot like this:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
set xdata time;    
plot 'thing1.txt' using 1:3 title 'thing 1', \
     'thing2.txt' using 1:3 title 'thing 2'
```

...however this seems to be overkill. Can this be achieved with Gnuplot without having to split the file into separate files-per-dataset? In reality there's about 200 separate labels, so if Gnuplot can automate the labelling it will save a lot of manual pre-processing of the data.

Comment: You really want 200 labels in your figure?

Comment: Initially yes. Ultimately I will be filtering it down so I'm only managing a handful (possibly less than 10) but I don't know what those are without doing some processing. I was hoping that visulising the data would save me writing a script to do the initial number crunching. Ultimately I'm looking for a trend, and want to know if that trend is common to everything or just a select few items so I know how next to proceed with the data. The input file is 400,000 lines so it's not something I can inspect by eye.

Comment: Did you consider writing a kind of wrapper script that generates the gnuplot-script and execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do something like this:

```
plot for [i=1:300] 'thing.txt' using 1:(($4 == i)? $3:NaN) title 'thing '.i
```

This won't be the most efficient (I'm pretty sure gnuplot'll read your file 300 times), but it'll get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Although the @mgilson's answer will work, it could be very slow if the data is big since it reads the file 300 times.

I think it is more efficient to put the labels by hand. If the labels are numbers, we can use them to select a color. For instance, the following lines will plot column 5 over column 1, where the color is selected from column 4, and the labels are placed by plotting an imaginary line with constant value NaN (1/0)

```
plot 'thing.txt' u 1:5:4 pt 7 lc variable notitle,\
     for [i=1:300] 1/0 w p pt 7 lc i title 'thing '.i
```

Notice that, by default, the gnuplot colors are cyclic, i.e each N lines the colors will be repeated (typically, N=9). You would need to set each of the 300 cases by hand if you need different colors for them. To do this automatically, [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633894/color-repetition-when-using-boxes-in-gnuplot) offers some good approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are similar questions, but later than yours. So, actually, those should be "duplicates" of your question. You have to filter your data as @mgilson suggested.

However, the existing answers might not be ideal, because @mgilson's solution will read the file many times and both @vagoberto's and @mgilson's solution will only plot with disconnected points.
I assume you want to plot connected lines either via `with lines` or `with linespoints`.

**Data:** `SO15790026.dat`

```
date       time       label      value
2013-03-17 10:09:28   thing 1    54
2013-03-17 10:09:32   thing 2    20
2013-03-17 10:10:02   thing 3    35
2013-03-17 10:10:03   thing 1    59
2013-03-17 10:10:21   thing 1    64
2013-03-17 10:10:37   thing 3    37
2013-03-17 10:10:37   thing 2    40
2013-03-17 10:10:42   thing 3    41
2013-03-17 10:10:44   thing 2    59
```

**Script 1:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

The "trick" to "bridge" missing data for gnuplot>=4.6.0 is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475591/7295599).

```
### filter data, gnuplot>=4.6.0
reset

FILE = "SO15790026.dat"

set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set grid x
set grid y
set key top left

plot for [i=1:3] x0=y0=NaN FILE u (column(4)==i?(y0=$5,x0=timecolumn(1)):x0):(y0) w lp pt 7 lc i ti sprintf("thing %d",i)
### end of script
```

**Script 2:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.7, Aug. 2017)

```
### filter data, gnuplot>=5.0.7
reset session

FILE = "SO15790026.dat"

myFilter(colD,colF,i) = column(colF)==i ? column(colD) : NaN

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M:%S" timedate
set datafile missing NaN
set grid x,y
set key top left

plot for [i=1:3] FILE u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(myFilter(5,4,i)) w lp pt 7 lc i ti sprintf("thing %d",i)
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]