# Color repetition when using boxes in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My data file has just two columns.The following MWE on those columns produces boxes with repeated colors. Is it possible to produce unique colors for each box?

```
reset
set term postscript eps size 5.5,4.5 enhanced color solid lw 2\
font "arial,28"
set key right
set xtics rotate -45 font ",20"
set style fill solid 1 border -1
plot 'rankdefcount.dat' using ($0):2:($0):xticlabels(1) \
                                          notitle w boxes lc variable 
quit
```

Here is the output I got:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few attempts and help from the SO experts, I came up with the following solutions; none of them perfect, though.

**Solution 1**: ( with a random repetition using **rand and rgb calls**)

```
reset
set term postscript eps size 5.5,4.5 enhanced color solid lw 2 font \
"arial,28"
set key right
rgb(r,g,b)=int(255*r)*65536+int(255*g)*256+int(255*b)
do for [i=1:31] {
   myrand=rand(int(rand(0)*i*100)+i*100)
   set style line i linecolor rgb rgb(rand(0),rand(0),rand(0))
}
set xtics rotate -45 font ",20"
set style fill solid 1 border -1
plot 'rankdefcount.dat' using ($0):2:($0):xticlabels(1) \
                                          notitle w boxes lc variable 
quit
```

Here is the corresponding output:

[image: rgb output]

**With palette definition (solution 2):**

```
reset
set term postscript eps size 5.5,4.5 enhanced color solid lw 2 font \
"arial,28"
set key right
set palette color model HSV
set palette defined (0 0 1 1,1 1 1 1)
set palette defined ( 0 0 1 0, 1 0 1 1, 6 0.8333 1 1, 7 0.8333 0 1)
set boxwidth 0.5
unset colorbox
set xtics rotate -45 font ",20"
set style fill solid 1 border -1
plot 'rankdefcount.dat' using ($0):2:($0):xticlabels(1) \
                                          notitle w boxes lc palette 
quit
```

This is the output:

[image: pal-redstart]

For another solution (**solution 3**), replace the definition above with the following lines:

```
set palette color model HSV
set pm3d explicit at b
set palette rgbformulae 3, 2, 2
```

This is what I got:

[image: pal-yellow]

Answer (score 1):

You may try and redefine as much linetypes as boxes you want to show. The code should go before the plot.

```
colors="black red orange #fa8072 ...." #[as much colors as needed] 
do for [L=1:words(colors)]{
set linetype L lc rgb word(colors,L)  
}
```

You can find colors for gnuplot here.

http://www.uni-hamburg.de/Wiss/FB/15/Sustainability/schneider/gnuplot/colors.htm

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a solution where I don't have to type the color names manually since the number of boxes is variable in my case. I have a solution using 'set palette' and 'lc palette' but that does not give me unique colors but only a gradient.  Ideally, the solution would have a combination of rand and rgb calls. With my limited knowledge of gnuplot, I could not construct one successfully.

Comment: If you get into palettes read http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/pm3dcolors.html Also take advantage of the following command `set palette maxcolors N` Wisely choosing the palette and the maxcolors make the palette looks less gradient-like and more independent color-like.

Comment: On the other hand in your output one can observe nine colors operating in a cycle. This is controlled by the command `set linetype cycle INTEGER` By increasing the cycle you may get more colors in you plot.