# conditional plot with lines in matplotlib

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, gnuplot

The following is my log file,

data.log

```
sa  4011    1259    3840    15      4864    19      156
sa  4011    1267    3840    15      5120    20      157
sa  4011    1275    3840    15      5376    21      158
sa  4010    1282    3072    3       1024    1       56
sd  4010    1283    2048    2       1024    1       41      QIO1
sa  4011    1283    3840    15      5632    22      159
sd  4011    1291    3584    14      5632    22      114     QIO1
sa  4011    1291    3840    15      5632    22      161
sa  4011    1299    3840    15      5888    23      162
sa  4011    1307    3840    15      6144    24      163
sa  4010    1314    3072    3       1024    1       60
sa  4011    1315    3840    15      6400    25      164
sd  4010    1323    2048    2       1024    1       46      QIO1
sa  4011    1323    3840    15      6656    26      166
```

I want to do a conditional plot, based on the  second column.
My x axis should be column 3,
y axis should be column 5. 
Since I have two different elements in column 2 (4010 and 4011), I need to use two colours. For example,

red can be used to represent the sa and sd of 4010 and
blue can be used to represent the sa and sd of 4010

I tried to do the above using gnuplot but could not succeed due to 
[Gnuplot: conditional plotting ($2 == 15 ? $2 : '1/0') with lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187691/gnuplot-conditional-plotting-2-15-2-1-0-with-lines)

I am trying to do this using matpyplot, but I am new to it. Can someone guide me how to proceed. This is how far I got.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl


data = np.loadtxt('data.log')
# plot the 3rd column as x, and 5th column as y
pl.plot(data[:,3], data[:,5], 'ro')
pl.xlabel('x')
pl.ylabel('y')

pl.show()
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments. Here is what I finally resorted to.

```
cat data.log | grep "^[sa|sd]" | while read l; do i=`echo $l |awk '{print $2}'`; echo $l >> ${i}.log; done
```

I got the two files 4010.log and 4011.log

```
set terminal png
set output 'overlay_image.png'

set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
set ytic auto
set yrange [0:63]

set autoscale

set grid
set title "queue size vs time (in ns)"
set xlabel "time (in ns)"
set ylabel "queue size"

set style data linespoints

plot "4010.log" using 3:5 title "IQ 0", \
     "4011.log"  using 3:5 title "IQ 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think your log file should even load using np.loadtxt because you have mixed types AND an inconsistent number of columns.  If you remove all of your "QI01" strings then you can load via loadtxt if you specify the type as str:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.log',dtype=str)
```

This still leaves you needing to convert to int (or float, whatever) to do the plotting.

```
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(data[:,3].astype(int),data[:,5].astype(int))
```

An alternative is to load directly into Pandas (perhaps overkill, perhaps not what you are interested in...but it is my answer so I get to throw it in!).  This has the benefit that you can load mixed types.  You still have an issue with your trailing "QI01" strings though.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('a.log',header=None,sep='\s+')
ax.plot(data[3],data[5])
```

I give the Pandas example not because it is SOOO useful here.  Rather, Pandas has so much utility in data analysis in general.  Since you are just starting out, or at least it sounds like you are, this may be a package you want to take a look at.

Comment: Thanks I shall try your solution and come back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code already plots something, you now just want to filter based on the second column:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt


data = np.loadtxt('data.log')

data4011 = data[data[:,1] == 4011]
data4010 = data[data[:,1] == 4010]
plt.plot(data4010[:,3], data4010[:,5], 'ro')
plt.plot(data4011[:,3], data4011[:,5], 'bo')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

Are you sure that you want `[:,3]` and not `[:,2]`? Columns are zero-based

Comment: I made a few modification (loaded my log file as string), but it gives me an index error.

Comment: Which line gives an index error? What is the error? Is `data.shape` what you expect it to be?

Comment: >>> plt.plot(data4010[:,3], data4010[:,5], 'ro')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
  . I was trying to use the data.shape[0] to extract the row size and iterate over it. But quickly realized, its much easier for me to overlay plots in gnuplot. I will post my answer.

Comment: Ok, 1/3. What is the exact error message, and what is `data.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

A matplotlib solution

We have to request some external modules

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The following enables us to slurp your data into a numeric array,

```
with open('category.dat') as f:
    data = np.array([[int(s) for s in line.strip().split()[1:8]] for line in f])
```

Note that I've discarded the first column and the optional last column, and that Python indexes arrays and lists starting from `0`...

<strike>We are ready to plot, we have two `cat`egorical variables so we do a `for` loop on them</strike>

```
for cat in (4010, 4011):
```

We are ready to plot, a different lines for each different categorical variable in column number `0`; the different `cat`egories are obtained casting the column into a `set`

```
for cat in set(data[:,0]):
    # indices is an array of booleans that indicates the rows where
    # row[0] is equal to the current value of cat
    indices = data[:,0] == cat

    # now we plot the second column (1 counting from zero) vs the 4th (i.e., 3)
    # I add a label to each curve
    plt.plot(data[:,1][indices], data[:,3][indices], "o-", label=str(cat))
```

Finally, out of the for loop, I draw the legend with the labels, I ensure that the y axis starts from zero and ask matplotlib to show the plot.

```
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

And here it is the product of such efforts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although, you couldn't solve your task in gnuplot, but you didn't say... what was your problem with gnuplot?

You can either compare column 2 with your keyword as string or as number. If it matches your keyword, the ternary operator will return the value in column 5 and `NaN` otherwise (check `help ternary`). However, a lines(points)-plot will be interrupted by `NaN` values, but if you `set datafile missing NaN` the line will be continuous.

**Script:**

```
### conditional plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
sa  4011    1259    3840    15      4864    19      156
sa  4011    1267    3840    15      5120    20      157
sa  4011    1275    3840    15      5376    21      158
sa  4010    1282    3072    3       1024    1       56
sd  4010    1283    2048    2       1024    1       41      QIO1
sa  4011    1283    3840    15      5632    22      159
sd  4011    1291    3584    14      5632    22      114     QIO1
sa  4011    1291    3840    15      5632    22      161
sa  4011    1299    3840    15      5888    23      162
sa  4011    1307    3840    15      6144    24      163
sa  4010    1314    3072    3       1024    1       60
sa  4011    1315    3840    15      6400    25      164
sd  4010    1323    2048    2       1024    1       46      QIO1
sa  4011    1323    3840    15      6656    26      166
EOD

myKeywords   = "4010 4011"
myKeyword(i) = word(myKeywords,i)
set key out

set datafile missing NaN
plot for [i=1:words(myKeywords)] $Data u 3:(strcol(2) eq myKeyword(i) ? $5 : NaN) w lp pt 7 ti myKeyword(i)
### end of script
```

In this case `set datafile missing NaN` only works for gnuplot>=5.0.7 (Aug 2017).

Workaround for gnuplot>=5.0.0 (Jan 2015)  (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475591/7295599))

```
plot for [i=1:words(myKeywords)] x0=y0=NaN $Data u (strcol(2) eq myKeyword(i) ? (y0=$5,x0=$3) : x0):(y0) w lp pt 7 ti myKeyword(i)
```

**Result:**

[image]