# gnuplot scatter plot selecting data on range of value in 3rd Column

Tags: select, plot, gnuplot

In a Windows 7 environment, I need to do a gnuplot scatter plot of 2 columns selecting data based on a range of values in a 3rd column. I know how to do it by creating separate data files for each range, but is it possible to do it by filtering on the data value in a 3rd column without awk
Thanks

> plot  "<awk '{if($3>=11 && $3<=19) print $0}' plot.dat " using 1:2 with points
> warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

I Presume the error is because I don't have awk in windows7 envirenment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (should be) many examples of filtering data with gnuplot here on StackOverflow, however, mostly combined with another issue. So, whenever I'm trying to search for a really good and clear example, it takes more time for searching than to simply write down the line.
You definitely don't need awk!

Attention: Filtered data will not be connected in a line plot. So, in case you want to plot *connected* filtered lines, e.g. `with lines` or `with linespoints` you need to prepend an extra line. I assume you have gnuplot>=5.0.
For older gnuplot versions you can check [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475591/7295599).

The following will plot column 1 versus column 2, but only if column 3 is in the range 11 to 19.

```
set datafile missing NaN
plot "myData.dat" u 1:($3>=11 && $3<=19 ? $2: NaN) w linespoints
```